# Управление между окнами во вкладке tmux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hotkeys, tmux

Допустим, я открыл *tmux* и одну вкладку разделил на несколько частей. Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу понять как перемещаться между частями этой вкладки, ведь команды `ctrl+b, число` служат для переключения между вкладками...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался... `ctrl+b, стрелочки`